# About regularized product of p-1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

I have a (newbie) doubt about the value of the regularized product of $p-1$ (being $p$ a prime number):

Is it the same
$$\prod^\infty{(p^{-s}-1)}$$
as
$$\prod^\infty{(1-p^{-s})}$$
? Why/why not?

On the one hand, don't think so, as, for example, taking $s=-1$ on the first equation we would get 
$$\prod^\infty{(p-1)}=\frac{4\pi^2}{\zeta{(1)}}=0$$
but taking it on the second equation we would get 
$$\prod^\infty{1-p^{-s}}=({\prod^\infty{(\frac{1}{1-p})}})^{-1} = {\zeta{(-1)}}^{-1}=-12$$
On the other hand, it seems obvious for me that $|1-a|=|a-1|$

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges iff the sequence $A(N) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n$ converges when $N \to \infty$. Now $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+c_n)$ converges iff the sequence $C(N) = \prod_{n=1}^N (1+c_n)$ converges and is non-zero as $N \to \infty$. The Euler product $\prod_p (1-p^{-s})^{-1}$ converges iff $Re(s) > 1$

Comment: **Please** use parentheses. Most of the formulas you wrote do not mean what you probably wanted them to mean.

Comment: What regularization are you referring to?